# Will I get an error if I try unscheduling a WP Cron scheduled task that wasn't scheduled?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron

So, I'm developing a plugin, I wanted to know if I call

```
$timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'scheduled_hook' );
wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, 'scheduled_hook' );
```

Without checking if it's scheduling at all, will it give me an error or will it just go through it and unschedule it in case it is actually scheduled and ignore it otherwise?

Comment: Sounds like you could easily test this, no? From the function signature, it seems that `wp_unschedule_event()` returns `WP_Error` on failure, so I would assume that this is what happens.

Comment: I actually could test it, but since I searched for the answer online and couldn't find, I decided to ask, so if anyone (like i did), searched for it, they could find the answer instead of having to test it
(And I could do some other stuff while testing it wasn't really critical!)

Comment: Valid reasons. I didn't mean to be harsh with my message - feel free to self-answer the question once you know the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, it does give errors for trying to unschedule something that isn't scheduled, but the answer is pretty easy and simple:

```
$timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'scheduled_hook' );
if ($timestamp) wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, 'scheduled_hook' );
```

Since `wp_next_scheduled` will return false for unscheduled hooks, a simple `if` in front of the call to `wp_unschedule_event` will prevent it from being called it there's nothing scheduled